# From a dataframe extract columns with numerical values

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to extract all columns for which the values are numeric from a dataframe, for a large dataset.

```
#generate mixed data
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 20)
df <- data.frame(letters[1 : 20], dat)
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
numdat <- df[,df == "numeric"]
```

That however leaves me without variables. The following gives an error.

```
dat <- df[,class == "numeric"]
Error in class == "numeric" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: `df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sapply

```
numdat <- df[,sapply(df, function(x) {class(x)== "numeric"})]
```